# Ошибка при отправке письма на почту tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def child_window():
   child_win = Toplevel()
   child_win.geometry("700x500")
   child_win.resizable(False, False)
   message_to = Label(child_win, text="Кому")
   message_to.place(x=10, y=13)
   message_subject = Label(child_win, text="Тема")
   message_subject.place(x=10, y=43)
   message_text = Label(child_win, text="Текст")
   message_text.place(x=10, y=75)
   from_id = Entry(child_win, width=80)
   from_id.place(x=50, y=15)
   subject = Entry(child_win, width=80)
   subject.place(x=50, y=45)
   main_message = Text(child_win, height=20, width=60)
   main_message.place(x=50, y=80)
   b4 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=lambda: send_message1(from_id, subject, 
   main_message))
   b4.place(x=50, y=420)


def send_message1(from_id, subject, main_message):
   mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
   addr_from = login2.get()  # Адресат
   addr_to = from_id.get()  # Получатель
   sub = subject.get()

   msg = MIMEMultipart()  # Создаем сообщение
   msg['From'] = addr_from  # Адресат
   msg['To'] = addr_to  # Получатель
   msg['Subject'] = sub  # Тема сообщения

   body = str(main_message.get())
   msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))  # Добавляем в сообщение текст
   mail.send_message(msg)
   mail.quit()  # Выходим
```

Мне нужно отправить на почту письма, я уже залогинился в другой функции. При отправке письма мне выдает ошибку. Как мне можно это исправить?

```
b4 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=lambda: send_message1(from_id, subject, 
main_message))
File "D:\mail\window.py", line 72, in send_message1
body = str(main_message.get())
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main_message` у вас объект `Text`. В отличие от `Entry`, для получения текста из `Text` с помощью метода `get` нужно указать "индексы" начала и конца извлекаемой части текста:

```
body = main_message.get(1.0, END)
```

В `str` дополнительно "на всякий случай" оборачивать не нужно, на выходе и так строка.